# Throwing data abort exception

Tags: linux, debugging, assembly, arm, memory-alignment

I was debugging the following code on [CPULator](https://cpulator.01xz.net/?sys=arm)

```
.global _start

_start:
  MOV R4, #0x61
  LDR R0, =freq
  ADD R0, R4
  LDR R2, [R0]
  ADD R2, #1
  STR R2, [R0]

_exit:
  MOV R7, #1
  SWI 0

.data
freq:   .rept 128
      .word 0x00 @ initialise character counts as 0
      .endr
```

I get an error on the CPULator console:

```
0000000c Warning: Memory read of 4 bytes at address 00000089 is misaligned. Throwing data abort exception.

Simulator requested a breakpoint.
```

The exception was thrown on line 7:

```
LDR R2, [R0]
```

Why is this and how can I solve it?

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is.  The code performs a misaligned load.  That is not allowed.

Comment: so how do i fix it? Sry if the qs is elementary, i am quite new to ARM

Comment: *so how do i fix it?* - can you explain what you are trying to do by this code? Do you really need to load a **32-bit word** from offset 0x61 of an array of zeroes? Increment it and save it back? We can't help much without knowing what the code *is supposed* to do.

Comment: @CrissHills Rewrite the code so it doesn't attempt to access memory at a misaligned address.  I can give more specific help if you give a more detailed problem description, including what you attempt to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the CPU is trying to access an odd address of the memory.

LDR R2, [R0] --> Load R2 with the content of the memory address referenced by R0

R0 contains and odd number.

All 32-bit and 64-bit CPU's can access even addresses of the memory:

0x00000000 is good
0x00000004 is good
0x00000008 is good
0x00000009 is not good

Enrico Migliore

P.S.

CPU's can only access: "aligned memory addresses" which are even addresses multiple of 4 or 8 depending on the CPU type.

A very few and special ARM instructions can access "unaligned addresses".

Take a look at here:

https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/oss-platforms/f/dev-platforms-forum/8806/loads-and-stores-for-unaligned-memory-addresses

Comment: ARM does not have instructions for unaligned memory access.  Either the ARM chip supports unaligned memory access (in which case all loads/stores except a few special ones can be used) or it doesn't (in which case none of them can be used).  The post you link even says that.  Note that ARMv8 and some ARMv7 parts do support unaligned memory access.

Comment: Add `.align 8` or something like that after `.data`; you should give the pseudo-op in the answer.